# Codeigniter displays a source code from controller.php instead of web page content

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am trying to run a small application in my development environment. This application was developed using codeigniter 3.0.

I have placed all my files in XAMPP\htdosc\My_APPName & restored the Database.

When I give the url "//Localhost/MY_APPName" it displays a source code from controller.php file. But the same files are working in production.

How can I resolve this issue?

PHP Version : 5.6.30
Apache : 2.4.25

Screen shot from browser:

[image]

Comment: you start <?php or not?

Comment: do other PHP files work, or is it just an issue with this one?  I suspect the PHP filter for apache isn't enabled

Comment: yes It  was starts with <?php &  ?>

Comment: yes i agree with @gabe3886 check your url it's localhost or not